# Git: LF is replaced by CLRF when I want LF?

Tags: c#, git, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity 3D C# project on Windows 10, and starting a new repository I add into my `.gitattributes` file:

```
# These files are text and should be normalized (convert crlf =&gt; lf)
* text=auto
*.cs text diff=csharp
```

I expected that when I add and commit files, git would convert CRLF to LFs in th Object Database (as described [here](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/)). Instead, I get messages like 
`warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in <file path/name>` which suggest the opposite. LF will be replaced with CRLF.

The functionality I want is my local Windows system to be able to mix LF/CRLF, but when committing it should convert CRLF to LF in text files.

Why am I getting the wrong functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had this issue at my job.
In your .gitattributes add:

`* text=auto eol=lf`

This is because Windows and Unix have different line endings. LF is for Linux, the above is the command to force save to LF.

Comment: So `text` doesn't mean LF?

Comment: `text` in this context, @BruceLee, is referring to the *type* of content, as opposed to, say, `image`. It's a lookup table: `text (content type) -> auto-end-of-line (setting name) -> LF (value)`

Comment: Or, to put it another way, `text` means: *yes, please edit this file* (other settings mean *no, do not edit this file*). The actual edit—the kind of line-ending changes to make—is determined by the `eol` setting, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a direct answer, but you can disable line ending warnings in VisualStudio, its the only IDE that complains anwyay (you can mix and match in vscode or mono)